# Move Mouse via jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, cursor, move

I've heard this isn't possible, but I'm just curious if anybody has some creative solution to my problem.

The page that is running is on a display LCD and the system itself is locked inside of a server room.

Basic question...

***Any way to move the mouse 1 pixel every 15 seconds for instance? It's a pain to get into the server room every time this flash file hiccups that I have running and the only fix is to just nudge the mouse for some reason.***

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: You're asking us the wrong question! -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You won't get this through the browser.  You need an application to do it for you.  Realistically though, look at the problem and fix that.  Don't just try to patch it.

Comment: Yeah, I have a little program I wrote in Python that accomplishes the same thing. I was just avoiding running .exe files on a server comp :-(

Comment: The browser is an exe :p

Comment: The browser is also a system installed .exe that wasn't written from some noober Python coder :-P

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below javascript function.

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',15000); // scrolls every 15 seconds.
}
```

Add the above function in the document.ready of the page.